# Reading Data from Oracle using Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Using Google Cloud Dataflow (Java code) -> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO class, we are reading data from oracle and writes it to Google Cloud SQL. While reading data from oracle, oracle monitoring system captured few information such as Machine_Name, UserName, OSUser, Module and LogonTime. In the column OSUSER oracle shows the value as "root" for the specified dynamic MachineName (which VM created dynamically). Is it possible to change that OSUserName from root to any other name like service account name? I know the VMs for Dataflow are created dynamically.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are concerned with the OSUSER column written to Google Cloud SQL with JdbcIO. And you would like to manually specify the username instead? And right not it just picks up a username from the machine, as 'root'? Do I understand correctly? Is OSUser a column you are manually populating with a PreparedStatement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Google, it’s not possible to change that OSUserName from root to any other name like service account name; it is not feasible to change the OSUser type for Cloud Dataflow GCE VM's due to Cloud Dataflow being a managed service by Google.